# Не работает invert на html

Tags: html, css, css3

Если я применяю `filter: invert(1);` к `html` или `body`, то они работают как-то странно.

Я ожидал, что 3 следующие примера будут выглядеть одинаково, однако, с фильтром на html и body получается инвертирование только кнопок и текста

[image: скриншот html и body]

а если аналогичные стили применить в блоку, то ожидаемым образом инвертируется и фон:

[image: скриншот нормального результата]

Почему так происходит?

```css
html {
  background: white;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<button>1</button> Не работает invert на html <button>2</button>
```

```css
body {
  background: white;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<button>1</button> Не работает invert на html <button>2</button>
```

```css
main {
  background: white;
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button>1</button> Не работает invert на html <button>2</button>
</main>
```

Comment: Возможно, это имеет какое-то отношение к [«The background of the root element becomes the canvas background»](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-backgrounds-3/#root-background)

Answer (score 6):

**¯\_(ツ)_/¯**

```css
html, body {
  background: white;
}

html {
  filter: invert(1);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button>1</button> Не работает invert на html <button>2</button>
</main>
```

---

> Может такое быть, что фильтру нужен цвет, а `background` не наследуется? - [@Doofy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1179076/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-invert-%D0%BD%D0%B0-html/1179077?noredirect=1#comment2051183_1179077)

Похоже это и есть ключ к разгадке.

**Firefox** показывает, что у `html` и `body` по дефолту `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0)`(`transparent`), если же мы возьмём предыдущий пример и будем увеличивать значение `aplha`, то можно предположить, что как раз таки `invert`у нужна "подложка" из фона.
*Но это не точно..*

```css
html, body {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  animation: A 2s steps(10) infinite;
}

html {
  filter: invert(1);
}

@keyframes A {
  100% {background-color: rgba(255,255,255,1);}
}
```

```html
<main>
  <button>1</button> Не работает invert на html <button>2</button>
</main>
```

Comment: Прикольно, но на вопрос "почему" не отвечает)

Comment: Может такое быть, что фильтру нужен цвет, а `background` не наследуется?

Comment: @Doofy, но у меня во всех трёх случаях background и filter вместе стоят на одном элементе. А работает из них только третий.

Comment: @Qwertiy: точного ответа пока нет, но люди тоже интересуются - [CSS filter:invert not working with background-color](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61265706/10179415)